# Responsive page: make the right column stay on top when in one column

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="left">
this is left side. it should go to the bottom when in one column
</div>
<div class="right">
this is right side. it should go to the top when in one column
</div>
```

css:

```
.left {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   .left, .right {
        width: 100%;
     }
}
```

I am hoping to make the right column stay on top when the display is one column.

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/m7zpoc30/1/

What should I do, including changes to my current CSS?

Comment: switch the order of your divs and float the right one right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of the divs so that right comes first in the html, and update the `class="right"` div to `float:right;`

https://jsfiddle.net/m7zpoc30/3/

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using flex, which might be of interest. You can wrap your left and right divs in a container with `display:flex`, and then use flex-direction on resize. See snippet below. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkfjqnk5/))

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  
}

.left {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .left, .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    this is left side. it should go to the bottom when in one column
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    this is right side. it should go to the top when in one column
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution! I chose the other one as the answer because of minimal changes to my code. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution using order flex property. 
See snippet below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  
}

.left {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
  order: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
.left {
    order: 2;
  }
.right {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    this is left side. it should go to the bottom when in one column
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    this is right side. it should go to the top when in one column
  </div>
</div>
```